# Умеет ли Webpack сам прописывать линки стилей в index.html

Tags: webpack

Есть потребность изучить принцип работы Webpack.

Немного работал с Gulp и знаю что есть определенные плагины, с помощью которых Gulp сам прописывает линки и пути к файлам стилей в index.html при сборке проекта

Работаю над TODO-list на Vue.js - тут соответственно применяется Webpack, а он стили либо инлайново подключает (сами они находсятся в build.js), либо с помощью плагина ExtractTextPlugin можно сформировать файл, но подключать нужно его опять же руками.

Может кто подсказать умеет так Webpack делать, если да, то что за плагин или просто хотя бы направление, в котором копать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите вот этот плагин: [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/html-webpack-plugin/)

Делает как раз то, что вам нужно

```
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: 'index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js'
  },
  plugins: [new HtmlWebpackPlugin()]
};
```

на выходе будет:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>webpack App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index_bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```